# Testing a site in the browser

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, web

I need to test functionality of my web-site inside the browser automatically, i.e. I want to start web browser, open my site, issue some mouse clicks and keyboard input, check that HTML DOM is modified appropriately to the input.
Are there any tools capable of doing this?

Comment: Might want to look at selenium a FFox plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it. What you do with that power is entirely up to you. Primarily it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that.

If you want full fledged testing, in my opinion, this is the tool to use.